# Ordering Months in Jan - Dec Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to order months from Jan to Dec instead of April to September, ASC and DESC doesn't work as it only sort it alphabetically.

```
SELECT COUNT( Inv_Num) AS 'NUM OF PURCHASES',  DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date])AS MONTH  
FROM tblInv_info
WHERE Inv_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date])
ORDER BY DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date]);
```

**Output**

```
135 April
125 August
125 December
137 February
125 January
143 July
128 June
130 March
138 May
136 November
125 October
142 September
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MONTH([Inv_Date])` in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT COUNT( Inv_Num) AS 'NUM OF PURCHASES', DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date])AS MONTH
FROM tblInv_info 
WHERE Inv_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' 
GROUP BY MONTH([Inv_Date]), DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date]) 
ORDER BY MONTH([Inv_Date]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to order by a value within the range:

```
SELECT COUNT( Inv_Num) AS num_purchases,  DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date]) AS MONTH  
FROM tblInv_info
WHERE Inv_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2020-12-31' 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, [Inv_Date])
ORDER BY MIN(Inv_Date);
```